# Missing Schema error

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I'm trying to index a model in Solr with django-haystack, but it returns me the following error(when using rebuild_index or update_index) :
it is giving me error

```
MissingSchema("Invalid URL %r: No schema supplied" % url)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'127.0.0.1:8983/solr/update/?commit=true': No schema supplied
```

This is search_indexes.py

```
from haystack import indexes
from haystack.indexes import SearchIndex
from jobpost.models import *



class JobIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    post_type = indexes.CharField(model_attr='post_type')
    location = indexes.CharField(model_attr='location')
    job_type = indexes.CharField(model_attr='job_type')
    company_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='company_name')
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')

    def get_model(self):
        return jobpost

    def index_queryset(self,**kwargs):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

Comment: Do you have a schema.xml in your solr configuration?

Comment: Does my answer fixes your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a full url including http in your haystack settings:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr'
  },
}
```